# Saving data to the database in exception handler - Spring

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, exception

Is this good practice to save some data in the database in exception handler in Spring?
In my database I have status of integration with external system and if I get exception during that integration I would like to set status to error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. If you have the proper design for Exception Handler as Business layer, I don't see any reason stopping you perform 'saving data' to database. Exception Handler as a Service bean and then get injected at Global scope is the normal standard I have see at many applications.

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any examples of that solution (handler as a service bean) ?

Comment: It`s wise to have a cleaning interval, too... For example 3 weeks or older :)

Comment: @piechos: if you are using Spring, please search Global Exception Handling.